# Pusher Private Channel Auth info required to subscribe to private-asdf

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, websocket, pusher

Trying to subscribe to a private channel with Pusher.  But every time it tries to subscribe I get the error below.  Which makes no sense since it's clearly returning the auth info.

```
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth info required to subscribe to private-sadfsadf"}}}
```

Normally it's returning the auth json (below) with status `200`.

```
"{\"auth\":\"0b1ce844906bd4d82cb4:21571e5667bf99f17bbf67ae0411594560748fde30b9edeca653653158f8a1f5\"}"
```

**Pusher PHP** (shortened)

```
$pusher = new Pusher($app_key, $app_secret, $app_id);
$auth = $pusher->socket_auth($postvars['channel_name'],  $postvars['socked_id']);
if ($auth)
    return $response->withJSON($auth);
else
    return $response->withStatus(403);
```

**Pusher JS**

```
var pusher = new Pusher('0b1ce844906bd4d82cb4', {
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true,
    authEndpoint: '{{site.uri.public}}/chat/auth/{{game.id}}',
    authTransport: 'ajax',
    auth: {
        params: {
            'csrf_name': '{{site.csrf.name}}',
            'csrf_value': '{{site.csrf.value}}'             
        },
        headers: {
            '{{site.csrf.name}}': '{{site.csrf.value}}'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and it was caused by having the BROADCAST_DRIVER set to redis instead of pusher.

Comment: This was also my case :) Thanks for anwser

Answer (score 1):

it was because my endpoint `/pusher/auth` returned the signature in JSON format.

So, I just changed this:

```
return $response
```

To this:

```
return json_decode($response)
```

NB: PUSHER signature use `hash_hmac` to generate hash:
you can compare you `entryPoint` return with

```
$sig = hash_hmac('sha256',$socket, $channelNam);

var_dump($sig);
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!